# Is it a good idea to add the relation in from A to B and B to A in an many to many relationship table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a self many to many relationship in this way.

```
TablaA
{
    IDTablaA bigint;
    Data varchar(200);
}

Relations
{
    ID bigint;
    IDRelated bigint;
}
```

I want to know which item from the TableA is related with the others elements of the TableA. So at first, no matter the order in the way that no matter if in ID I set one ID and in IDRelated I set another or at contrary.

I mean, no matter if I insert (2,3) or (3,2) because in the both cases I will can know which elements are related.

So the query it would be something like that:

```
select * from TableAas t where

t.IDtableA IN(select r.IDRelated from Relations as r where r.ID = 2)
or
t.IDtableA IN(select r.ID from Relations as r.IDRelated = 2)
```

So I am thinking that I could add two rows in the middle table, (2,3) and (3,2). I duplicate the information, but if I want to get all the items that are related with 2, I only need to search for ID = 2, and not ID = 2 or IDRelated = 2;

So the query it would be something like that:

```
select * from TableAas t where

t.IDtableA IN(select r.IDRelated from Relations as r where r.ID = 2)
```

I only use a subquery and if I need to set more conditions in the related items, the query could be more complex. The problem is that I will duplicate the rows in the Relations table.

So I would like to know which is best option, duplicate rows to have an easier query or not duplicate but I will have a more complex query.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can have a key that references another column in the same table, and it is very common to find data like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I would like to know which is best option, duplicate rows to have an easier query or not duplicate but I will have a more complex query.

There's not a simple answer of which one is best here.  This is a grey area of relational modeling, and both opinions and practice differ.  They are both reasonable design choices.

Typically in an OLTP system you will favor designs that eliminate redundant storage of data, optimizing for the simplicity and performance of the transactions that add or change the data in the database.  And so you would default to storing only one row.

Conversely in an OLAP system you will optimize for the simplicity and performance of historical queries.  And so you would default to storing both.

Note that in an OLTP ststem if you store only one row, you would also want a CHECK constraint forcing `ID < IDRelated`  to ensure that you don't get the *same* relationship entered twice.  And if you store both you would want a trigger to enforce that the inverse is stored also.